# Newly created input-element ignoring attribute changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Why does

> $("<input type='text' value='Foo' />").val("Bar")

result in an object (as shown in the debugger console):

> <input type="text" value="Foo">

Shouldn't the value be "Bar" now that I changed it?

My guess is that it has something to do with the element not being part of the document.
How can I work around this limitation?

I would like to avoid inserting the element into the document at that point. However, later code which uses `attr("value")` should get the correct result.

Comment: That's interesting. I've never tried manipulating an HTML element prior to inserting it; I'll have to play around with this for a while.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Innuendo108/Uf2J3/

Comment: @stealthyninja: try the same code in your debugger console. It will not yield the same result: $('<div></div>').append($("<input type='text' value='Foo' />").val("Bar"))[0].innerHTML returns "<input type='text' value='Foo' />"

Comment: Hmm - it seems that only the HTML is not actualized, but the attribute values themselves are: http://jsfiddle.net/U9wzZ/1/ - maybe my actual error lies somewhere else as I used the HTML for debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - I finally found and resolved the issue:

Firstly, as pointed out in the comment, the HTML of detached elements (especially the attributes) does not seem to be kept in sync with the actual element properties. This happens after inserting the elements into the document.
This problem I am aware now caused me many headaches debugging my code and made it impossible to find the second one. Thanks for helping me discovering it!

Secondly, I am looping through the attributes of the elements using their "attributes" property.
A short illustration (without the loop):

```
var $input = $("<input type='text' value='Foo' />");
$input.val("Bar");     
alert($input.attr("value") + " - " + $input.get(0).attributes["value"].value);
```

This code alerts "Bar - Foo" as long as $input is not part of the document.
I fixed this problem by replacing calls to `attribute.value` with calls to `$element.attr(attribute.name)`.

Answer (score 1):

[In this test](http://jsbin.com/efoku3/edit) the element is not inserting into the document and its value is "Bar", as expected. May be something wrong with the console.

Answer (score 0):

Would you do this?
http://jsfiddle.net/mazzzzz/q6bfp/1/